# Alamofire error sessionDeinitialized ssl certificate

Tags: swift, xcode, networking, alamofire

I'm testing Alamofire with ssl certificate.

using swift and swiftUI I wrote this 2 functions to load the ssl from a bundle and make the request using Alamofire.

```
 func getCertificate() -> [SecCertificate] {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ssl", withExtension: "cer")
        
        
        let localCer = try! Data(contentsOf: url!) as CFData
        
        guard let certificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(nil, localCer) else {
            return []
        }
        return [certificate]
    }
```

```
 func loginUserIcrew(userName: String, password: String){
       
        
        let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
            linkIcrew: PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates:getCertificate())
        ]
        let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
        
        
        let session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)
        
        
        session.request (linkIcrew,method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
            .response { response in
                
                print(response)
                
                
            }
        
    }
```

and I using it in a simple button like this

```
struct SalaryStart: View {
    @ObservedObject var ss = SalaryManager()
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            ss.loginUserIcrew(userName: "user", password: "pass")
        } label: {
            Text("test")
        }

    }
}
```

I'm getting the error : `Alamofire.AFError.sessionDeinitialized`

any help how to solve tis issue? reading online looks like the session need to keep alive, but I don't understand what does it mean??

thanks for the help

Comment: how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`sessionDeinitialized` means what it says: your `Session` was deinitialized while the request was in progress and so it was cancelled. You need to keep the `Session` alive at least long enough to complete the request. Usually you want to use a single `Session` for all of your requests, so I suggest keeping it as a singleton.

Comment: how to do that? a single session? can you please show an example?

Comment: Can you show an example of how to do this?